# Rails 4 Amazon S3 background url images file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

Is there a way to make url in css to work with asset pipeline
Like the one below?

`background: url("../assets/pattern/black_paper.png")`

I'm getting file not found and I'm using S3 and Heroku on Rails 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
background: asset_url("pattern/black_paper.png");
```

It works for me without renaming CSS files.

Comment: could you do this under `.css` files though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Rename all your CSS files to css.erb
2. change your snippet of code to:

   background: url(<%= asset_path '/pattern/black_paper.png' %>)